# How can I effectively design and fetch associated documents in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Currently I have two models in my application - for users and comments. The simplified structure is as follows:

**User**

```
{
    id : "01",
    username : "john"
}
```

**Comment**

```
{
    id : "001",
    body : "this is the comment"
}
```

Now I would like to associate users with their comments. Coming from SQL world, the first thing coming to my mind is simply adding `user_id` field in comment document and then use JOIN, but I guess it's not an optimal solution in terms of efficiency.

The other solution could be to embed comments in user's document:

```
{
    id : "01",
    username : "john",
    comments : [
        {
        id : "001",
        body : "this is the comment"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm going to query for comments very often, e.g. when showing all comments from the past 24 or 48 hours. And alongside with the comment, I want to display the username.

I could of course add `username` field to the comment document. But then I have username stored in two places - in users collection and comments collection.

What is the best approach here?

Comment: Well, in case of separate collections, most efficient way is to use `$lookup` if you have MongoDB 3.2. see https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Answer (score 0):

If you have a very huge number of comments per user, it is not a good option to put those comments as sub-document of the `user` collection. It will not increase the efficiency. The best option will be to put the `user_id` in the `comment` collection and creating an index on that field.